# lvalue and rvalue reference can combine in one?

Tags: c++

I found the below link which said "lvalue and rvalue reference interface can combine in one".
[Pass lvalue to rvalue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14667921/pass-lvalue-to-rvalue)

but when I take it for example. compile error appeared `cannot bind ‘std::string {aka std::basic_string}’ lvalue to ‘std::string&& {aka std::basic_string&&}’`. Below is my implementation.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void g(string &&b) {
    cout << b << endl;
}

void g(const string &b) {
    cout << b << endl;
}

void f(string &&a) {
    g(std::forward<string>(a));
}

int main()
{
    f("1122");
    string a("222");
    f(a);
    return 0;
}
```

I mean "void f(string &&a)" and "void f(const string &a)" can combine in one. Then we just need to call "void f(string &&a)", which can both receive rvalue reference and lvalue by preface forward.

--------- Add description

this may be call `universal reference`

Comment: Which answer to the linked question are you trying to follow? The one that uses a template (unlike your code) or the one that directs execution *to* a unified function (your code goes *from* a unified function)? Neither is a perfect match to what you've done, and you linked to the question instead of to a specific answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To combine an r-value reference and l-value reference into a single reference, you need to use a so called **universal reference**. These are defined in C++ via `auto &&` or a template with a && reference. See for example [What is move semantics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106110/what-is-move-semantics/11540204#11540204) , though, quite exceptionally, I guess you'll find more approachable explanations outside of stackoverflow. Search for "universal reference C++".

Now, back to your code. All you need is this:

```
template <typename T>
void f(T &&a) 
{
    g(std::forward<string>(a));
}
```

That's it. A universal reference defined via a template plus a &&-reference. Notice that I had to replace `string` with `T`.

However, simplicity is our best friend. If you don't need a template, why not go for the old, good const reference?

```
void f(const string & a) 
{
  g(a);
}
```

To me, it is the preferable solution.

Comment: thx for you clearly answer! but I have an queue class already use the `A universal reference defined via a template plus a &&-reference` but it can success pass rvalue but can not pass lvalue. what can be the problem? it's a class member function with template.

Comment: @dahohu527, my guess: you have a class template `template<class T> class my_class { ... };` with a member function `void foo(T&&)`. In this case `T&&` is not a universal reference, but just an rvalue reference, and rvalue references can't bind to lvalues. If you had `template<class S> foo(S&&)`, `S&&` would be a universal reference.

Comment: @Evg Yes you're right, It is really difficult to understand. This article helps a lot. https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers